# Return string possible from "await Task.Run(() => Parallel.ForEach"?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Wondering if it's possible to make the string return via the await call.

```
    public static async Task<string[]> GetCode(IEnumerable<CodeAddressContainer> codeList, int count)
    {

        string[] stringArray = new string[count];

        await Task.Run(() => Parallel.ForEach(codeList, code =>
        {
            var id = code.Id;
            var asm = code.ASM;
            var address = code.Address;

            var hexCode = CompileCodeToPairedHex(asm);

            var lines = hexCode.GetNonEmptyLineCount();

            address = GetInsertionAddress(address, lines);

            string result = address + Environment.NewLine + hexCode;

            stringArray[id] = result;
        }));

        return stringArray;
    }
```

Would be a bit smoother if it's possible.
I can't find anything on what values you can return via that.

Only reason i have async Task though is just to be able to run the method async.

Comment: why not just use a normal `foreach`, start a task for each item, and use `await Task.WhenAll`

Comment: please elaborate:)

Comment: "Only reason i have async Task though is just to be able to run the method async." --- this sounds awkward :-S

Comment: @zerkms is there a better way to run something without freezing the GUI thread?

Comment: @Zerowalker if something is not asynchronous - don't make it so - it would be the client (the calling site) responsibility. What you are doing is an antipattern and is considered harmful.

Comment: @zerkms it's being called on a button press, i don't know how to do it much other ways, other than run it on another thread which calls on even on completion or something.

Comment: @Zerowalker run it asynchronously in the click handler. http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html

Comment: @zerkms i think i did something like that at start, and i thought it was the wrong way to do it and the deeper you go, the better.
Don't quite understand how using a task from within the button compares to using it on the first method call, feels like the result should be identical?

Comment: @Zerowalker "feels like the result should be identical" --- technically - yes. Practically, if something is not asynchronous - don't make it so. The article explains it all.

Comment: @zerkms got it, thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
    public static async Task<string[]> GetCode(IEnumerable<CodeAddressContainer> codeList, int count)
    {
        return await Task.Run<string[]>(() => codeList.AsParallel().AsOrdered().Select(code =>
        {
            var id = code.Id;
            var asm = code.ASM;
            var address = code.Address;

            var hexCode = CompileCodeToPairedHex(asm);

            var lines = hexCode.GetNonEmptyLineCount();

            address = GetInsertionAddress(address, lines);

            string result = address + Environment.NewLine + hexCode;

            return result;
        }).ToArray());
    }
```

Comment: How about elements order?

Comment: Elements order seemed not to be addressed in original code.

Comment: `stringArray[id] = result;` --- are you sure?

Comment: @zerkms, and would you be sure about the order of `id` values in that sequence? :)

Comment: I am sure that the code in the question **guarantees the consistent order.** And your code does not.

Comment: éc, you were saying as if you were the author of question.

Comment: You don't have to be the author to know how arrays work. The same input provides the same output for the code in the question. And your code does not.

Comment: my code does indeed need to put the code in the correct order:)

Comment: You can just do `.AsParallel().AsOrdered().Select(` and the output list will be the same order as the input

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot return from the `Task.Run` since it is an inside function which is awaited, which means that the control is sent back to the caller at this point.

However if you just care about keeping the method `async`, you can do something along the line of using await to convert the `IENumerable` to list and the rest is easy:

```
public static async Task<string[]> GetCode(IEnumerable<CodeAddressContainer> codeList, int count)
{
    var list = await codeList.ToListAsync();

    string[] stringArray = new string[count];

    Parallel.ForEach(codeList, code =>
    {
        var id = code.Id;
        var asm = code.ASM;
        var address = code.Address;

        var hexCode = CompileCodeToPairedHex(asm);

        var lines = hexCode.GetNonEmptyLineCount();

        address = GetInsertionAddress(address, lines);

        string result = address + Environment.NewLine + hexCode;

        stringArray[id] = result;
    }

    return stringArray;
}
```

Comment: Hmm that's indeed one way to do it.

Comment: `await codeList.ToListAsync()` --- what this is for actually?